Extract duration from interval during working hours in PostgreSQL
I have a table that stores data about events with id, start_timestamp (timestamp with time zone), end_timestamp (timestamp with time zone) and duration (in seconds):
create table my_table(
  id bigint generated by default as identity primary key
, start_timestamp timestamptz
, end_timestamp timestamptz
, duration bigint);
insert into my_table values
 (0,    '2024-10-01 03:00:00+00',   '2024-10-01 15:00:00+00',   43200)
,(1,    '2024-10-02 05:00:00+00',   '2024-10-03 17:00:00+00',   129600)
,(2,    '2024-10-04 12:00:00+00',   '2024-10-07 09:45:00+00',   251100);

Now the data I need to get from it is The duration of each event during working hours, which means 9:00 - 18:00, Monday to Friday.
Below are the expected results from each row with an explanation:
Event ID #0



id
start_timestamp
end_timestamp
duration
working_hours_duration




0
2024-10-01 03:00:00+00
2024-10-01 15:00:00+00
43200
21600



The event started before working hours, the time from 2024-10-01 03:00:00+00 should be ignored, and the difference between 2024-10-01 09:00:00+00 - 2024-10-01 15:00:00+00 should be calculated. The expected result would be 21600 (seconds).
Event ID #1



id
start_timestamp
end_timestamp
duration
working_hours_duration




1
2024-10-02 05:00:00+00
2024-10-03 17:00:00+00
129600
61200



Now the event not only started before working hours, but also ended the next day, meaning that a gap between two working days should also be excluded. So, the expected result would be all working hours range for 2024-10-02, which would be 09:00 to 18:00, and 09:00 till 17:00 for the 2024-10-03. It totals up to 17h, so the expected result would be 61200 (seconds).
Event ID #2



id
start_timestamp
end_timestamp
duration
working_hours_duration




2
2024-10-04 12:00:00+00
2024-10-07 09:45:00+00
35820
24300



This one is the most complicated, as it also includes weekend, which should be subtracted from the duration.
So, the event starts at Friday (2024-10-04) 12:00. So all the time till the end of that working day should be included (18:00 - 12:00 = 6 hours). Then the weekend starts, so everything till start of the work hours on Monday (2024-10-07) 09:00 should be ignored. And on Monday the duration would be 09:45:00 - 09:00:00 = 00:45. All of it should be summed up, so the result is 6h45' = 24300 (seconds).
Question:
Is it something that's possible to achieve solely on PostgreSQL side, by a query, or should I simply fetch the raw data and process it in the backend instead?

Should be fairly easy if you make these into tstzranges, intersect them with a *, then and grab upper()-lower() of the result.

Unrelated but column duration is redundant as it's exactly extract(epoch from end_timestamp - start_timestamp)::bigint


Consider using one tstzrange instead of start/end. They're easier to work with and index. 2) Don't store derived values like duration. If start_timestamp or end_timestamp change, duration might not be updated. Instead use a generated column or view.


Yet another approach to the same idea: as I initially complained, calculating the lengths purely arithmetically should be way faster than constructing even partial calendars from series of generated timestamps.
This is the fastest example so far, thanks to eliminating generate_series() completely:
demo at db<>fiddle
with cte as (
select*,tstzmultirange(tstzrange(start_timestamp,end_timestamp))*
        tstzmultirange(case when date_part('isodow',start_timestamp) in (1,2,3,4,5) then
                       tstzrange( date_trunc('day',start_timestamp)+'09:00'::interval
                                 ,date_trunc('day',start_timestamp)+'18:00'::interval)
                       else tstzrange('empty') end
                      ,case when date_part('isodow',end_timestamp) in (1,2,3,4,5) then
                       tstzrange( date_trunc('day',end_timestamp)+'09:00'::interval
                                 ,date_trunc('day',end_timestamp)+'18:00'::interval)
                       else tstzrange('empty') end) as first_last_day_overlap
from your_table)
select id
     , start_timestamp
     , end_timestamp
     , make_interval(hours=>(
                     45*greatest(0,( date_trunc('week',end_timestamp)::date
                                    -date_trunc('week',start_timestamp)::date)/7-1)
                     +case when date_trunc('week',start_timestamp)
                              <>date_trunc('week',end_timestamp)
                           then 9*greatest(0, 5-date_part('isodow',start_timestamp))
                               +9*greatest(0,-1+date_part('isodow',end_timestamp))
                           else 9*greatest(0,least(5,date_part('isodow',end_timestamp))
                                             -date_part('isodow',start_timestamp)
                                             -1)
                      end)::int)
      +coalesce((select sum(upper(r)-lower(r)) 
                 from unnest(first_last_day_overlap)r),'00:00') worktime_overlap
from cte;

What it does is it reduces the calendar intersection to one flat operation and trades the entire generated part for a few additions and multiplications.

Construct a tstzmultirange out of each start and end.
Make another range out of the working hours on the dates of start and end, but only if those happen on a workday.
Intersect these ranges using the * operator and checks the width of the result.
Add

45h for each week separating start and end
9h for each full day between start and end, if they are both in the same one week. Otherwise

9h for each full day between start and the end of the week it's on
9h for each full day between end and the start of the week it's on








id
start_timestamp
end_timestamp
worktime_overlap
worktime_overlap_seconds




0
2024-10-01 03:00:00+00
2024-10-01 15:00:00+00
06:00:00
21600


1
2024-10-02 05:00:00+00
2024-10-03 17:00:00+00
17:00:00
61200


2
2024-10-04 12:00:00+00
2024-10-07 09:45:00+00
06:45:00
24300


3
2024-10-09 12:00:00+00
2024-10-21 09:45:00+00
69:45:00
251100


4
2024-01-13 15:57:22.608+00
2024-05-30 15:15:12.4704+00
888:15:12.4704
3197712.4704



In a test on 3k randomised ranges that can span up to a year, this takes 45ms. You can push this idea further and do the whole thing as just a bunch of conditional statements:



exec time
comment
example




40 ms
no generate_series(), no unnest(), no ranges, just a bunch of conditionals
...


45 ms
no generate_series()
this


244 ms
generating only the week the start and end are in
in the demo


888 ms
generating dates straight into count(*)filter()
2nd attempt


1'254 ms
generating the whole worktime calendar between each start and end
Stefanov.sm's


1'374 ms
generating the whole worktime calendar between each start and end
initial answer


2'698 ms
generating one large calendar between earliest start and latest end
Frank Heikens'


3'998 ms
generating the whole worktime calendar between each start and end
ValNik's




I've taken down the two earlier answers to clean up the thread. This answer addresses those approaches and still has them in the demo, so they are no longer worth displaying separately.

Zegarek, thanks for the interesting solutions and comparing the performance of different queries on the model. The preference for options should take into account the typical duration of the intervals. For long intervals, calculation without unnest and generate will be preferable. I tried to compare query performance on shorter interval durations, on your model(https://dbfiddle.uk/dEnWyBiA)

@ValNik The fiddle you pasted just shows the comparison from the end of my answer above. If I reduce the maximum range span to 9 days and increase the test sample set size to 40k rows, this remains the fastest example here: demo. Same with max width of 4 days: demo. Note that these show multiple versions of my code and this one's the one at the very end of each fiddle.

I would first create a helper function that splits the interval end_timestamp - start_timestamp into daily intervals. It might be useful for other cases too.
create or replace function daily_list(from_ts timestamptz, to_ts timestamptz)
returns setof timestamptz[] immutable parallel safe language sql as 
$$
  select array [greatest(s, from_ts), least(s + interval '1 day - 1 us', to_ts)] 
  from generate_series(date_trunc('day',from_ts),date_trunc('day',to_ts),interval '1 day') s;
$$;

Then use a scalar subquery for working_hours_duration.
select my_table.*, extract(epoch from 
 (
   select sum(case when extract(isodow from dl[1]) not in (6, 7) -- skip holidays
           then least(dl[2]::time,'18:00') - greatest(dl[1]::time,'09:00') end)
   from daily_list(start_timestamp, end_timestamp) as dl
 ))::integer as working_hours_duration
from my_table;




id
start_timestamp
end_timestamp
duration
working_hours_duration




0
2024-10-01 03:00:00 +0300
2024-10-01 15:00:00 +0300
43200
21600


1
2024-10-02 05:00:00 +0300
2024-10-03 17:00:00 +0300
129600
61200


2
2024-10-04 12:00:00 +0300
2024-10-07 09:45:00 +0300
251100
24300



DB Fiddle demo
Note: The function body of daily_list may be used as a subquery in brackets in the query above and then no function definition would be necessary.
select my_table.*, extract(epoch from 
(
 select sum(case when extract(isodow from dl[1]) not in (6, 7) 
         then least(dl[2]::time, '18:00') - greatest(dl[1]::time, '09:00') end)
 from
 (
  select array [greatest(s, start_timestamp), least(s + interval '1 day - 1 us', end_timestamp)] 
  from generate_series (date_trunc('day', start_timestamp), date_trunc('day', end_timestamp), interval '1 day') s
 ) as t(dl)
))::integer as working_hours_duration
from my_table;



Your results are off: they need to be 21600, 61200, 24300. Yours are 3600, 7200, 3600 seconds (1h, 2h, 1h) too high, so I'm guessing you have an off-by-one error somewhere.

@Zegarek Very true, thanks. I put the start of the working hours wrong, 08:00 instead of 09:00. Now fixed.

Thanks for addressing this. I'm still seeing a small difference in a few cases but I didn't read into this enough to know if that's only rounding or truncating something along the way, or if it's really off: in this test rows 5 and 8 are just rounded/truncated but 4 and 9 are either off or just show the difference amplified because the value shifted earlier.

First, divide (expand) the multi-day intervals into rows of 1 day in each row, using generate_series(...).
Value
extract('day' from(date_trunc('day',end_timestamp)-date_trunc('day',start_timestamp))) ddif

is count of days in interval.
Then we will join expanded event time table with work schedule table (timetable) on week day as exp_event_table.date.day_of_week=timetable.day_of_week.
In expanded event table start and end timestamp's have same day of week.
In work shedule time table, we explicitly indicate the beginning and end of working hours by day of the week. Such a table is clearer and more convenient to maintain.
Timetable key is day of week ('mon',....'sun').
See example
with timetable as(
  select cast(dname as varchar(3)) dname,work_start::time,work_end::time
  from (values ('mon','9:00','18:00'),('tue','9:00','18:00')
              ,('wed','9:00','18:00'),('thu','9:00','18:00')
              ,('fri','9:00','18:00'),('sat','0:00','00:00')
              ,('sun','0:00','00:00')
       )t(dname,work_start,work_end)
)
select id,start_timestamp,end_timestamp,duration
  ,sum(extract('epoch' from (wday_end_dttm-wday_start_dttm))) new_duration
from(
  select *
    ,case when dd=0 then 
       dt+least(greatest(start_tm,work_start),work_end) 
     else dt+tt.work_start
     end wday_start_dttm
    ,case when dd=ddif then dt+greatest(least(end_tm,work_end),work_start) 
     else dt+tt.work_end
     end wday_end_dttm
  from(
     select *
       ,date_trunc('day',start_timestamp+(cast(dd as varchar)||' day')::interval ) dt
     from( 
       select id,start_timestamp,end_timestamp,duration
         ,start_timestamp::time start_tm,end_timestamp::time end_tm
         ,extract('day' from(date_trunc('day',end_timestamp)-date_trunc('day',start_timestamp))) ddif
       from test
     )a
     cross join generate_series(0,ddif,1)dd
  )b
  left join timetable tt on tt.dname=to_char(dt,'dy')
)c
group by id,start_timestamp,end_timestamp,duration
order by id




id
start_timestamp
end_timestamp
duration
new_duration




0
2024-10-01 03:00:00+00
2024-10-01 15:00:00+00
43200
21600.000000


1
2024-10-02 05:00:00+00
2024-10-03 17:00:00+00
129600
61200.000000


2
2024-10-04 12:00:00+00
2024-10-07 09:45:00+00
251100
24300.000000



More details in fiddle

Ranges and multiranges in combination with a calender can solve this issue in plain SQL:
WITH r AS (
    SELECT id, range_agg(TSRANGE(g + '09:00'::TIME, g + '18:00'::TIME)) * TSMULTIRANGE(TSRANGE(start_time, end_time)) AS working_hours
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2024-10-01'::TIMESTAMP, '2024-11-01'::TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL '1 day') g(s)
        , (VALUES
               (0, '2024-10-01 03:00:00'::TIMESTAMP, '2024-10-01 15:00:00'::TIMESTAMP)
               ,(1, '2024-10-02 05:00:00'::TIMESTAMP, '2024-10-03 17:00:00'::TIMESTAMP)
               ,(2, '2024-10-04 12:00:00'::TIMESTAMP, '2024-10-07 09:45:00'::TIMESTAMP)
           ) AS sub(id, start_time, end_time)
    WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM s) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 -- weekdays
    GROUP BY id, start_time, end_time
), seconds_per_day AS (
    SELECT  id, working_hours
        ,   EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM UPPER(UNNEST(working_hours)) - LOWER(UNNEST(working_hours))) seconds
    FROM r)
SELECT id, SUM(seconds)
FROM seconds_per_day
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;

In this example I used generate_series(), better to replace this by a table that holds a complete calendar including holidays etc.
It's the multirange operator * that does all the work to compute the intersection.
